# Hyperlinks in blog are not showing underlined

Tags: entries, post

I'm brand new to Craft, having been a Wordpress user. I'm managing a site for a small charity.
Having done some new pages and a blog page without any problem, I did a blog yesterday in which the hyperlinks are live are not visible (ie not showing as underlined). I've tried various different routes for getting the text to use, and tried a new blog, but with no luck.
Can anyone help me? ...in as plain English as possible please, I'm not familiar yet with html or Craft language.
The blog post I've don that is fine is:
https://timetoshineleeds.org/blog/learning-lunches-and-breakfasts-and-teas
\the blog post that won't show the hyperlinks is:
https://timetoshineleeds.org/blog/free-training-opportunity-project-management

Thank you very much
Rob

Comment: Thank you for reading my post - but someone offline has now resolved it for me - in case it's useful to anyone else, I was using a different style of 'body text'

Answer (score 2):

Hyperlink styles are defined in you stylesheet (CSS).

Applying the underline text-decoration property like so:

```
text-decoration: underline;
```

Answer (score 0):

Link styling is done with CSS. In your case, you should to narrow your styling to links that are within your "body-copy" div that wraps your CMS content. If you apply this CSS rule:

```
a { text-decoration: underline; }
```

You will see underlines on every "a" element on the page. If you apply this CSS rule, you'll only see underlines on links within the "body-copy" div:

```
.body-copy a { text-decoration: underline; }
```